Fabric.js Textbox does not wrap long text.(version 5.3.0)
I'm using fabric.js version 5.3.0.
Textbox object will wrap text when you add space between words but not wrap when you add text without space.
Please check below fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Niketa_patel/fo5q1bzt/10/
Here is the code:
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var str = 'Please type a long word and watch me break!';
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox(str, {
    width: 200,

});
canvas.add(textbox);
function setcharspacing(){
textbox.set('charSpacing',100);
canvas.renderAll();
}


I have also tried custom function to wrap the text but it's not working with charSpacing.
Here is the referral link which I have tried:
https://jjwilly.com/blog/fabricjs-2-0-breakwords
Expectation:
should wrap text proper when you add text without space with charSpacing(charSpacing value between -100 to 100)
It would be really appreciated if anyone can help me.
Thank you !

You can use the property splitByGrapheme, Seems to be made just for this scenario!


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox(str, {
    width: 200,
    breakWords: true,
        splitByGrapheme :true,
});
canvas.add(textbox);
function setcharspacing(){
textbox.set('charSpacing',100);
canvas.renderAll();
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<button id="charspcing" onclick = setcharspacing()>
setcharspcing
</button>




why cursor not sowing at the end of the text?
it's showing middle of the text.
You can check by select all the text , it'll select only half of the text.
